# Disable UPnP safe?

Tags: upnp

Is it safe to disable upnp or can it harm devices on the network?
Are there any other problems disabling the UPnP might bring

The reason I'm turning it of is so I can play battlefield 3

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem if you have no devices that rely on UPnP on your network.

Comment: What kind of  devices would that be?

Comment: You will have to check all the devices that connect to your network, and see if any of those use UPnP. I presently do not have anything that uses UPnP, so I can't help much in that aspect.